# Avoiding many typecasting

Tags: c++, casting

I'm creating a UI system for my OpenGL application and I have this design...

The UI manager:

```
class UIManager {
public:
  UIElement *add(UIElement *element);
}
```

Example element:

```
class Button : public UIElement {
public:
  Button(UIElement *parent, const string &caption, const Point &position);
}
```

Now everytime I want to instantiate a button and keep the pointer to it, I'll have to write this:

```
// somewhere in the header file
UIManager *manager;
Button *button1, *button2;

// in cpp
button1 = static_cast<Button *>(manager->add(new Button(0, "Enter", Point(10, 10))));
button2 = static_cast<Button *>(manager->add(new Button(0, "Exit", Point(10, 50))));
```

which looks a bit lengthy to me, especially when I have a dozen of elements.

Is this a bad design? Is there another way to get over this?

Comment: That's a very odd program design...

Comment: I don't know if it's a copy-paste error, but in your example `button2` is _not_ declared as a pointer.

Comment: Are you interested in some part of the `Button` public interface that is not a part of `UIElement`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, that was a typo.

Comment: OK, is ``UIManager`` an abstract base class, or can you use it directly?

Comment: Did you mean `UIElement`? It is an abstract base class and I cannot use it directly.

Comment: No, I mean ``UIManager``. If it wasn't abstract, you could use a template method with no casting. But if it is abstract, you can't do that...

Comment: Anyway, I added an answer with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declate `add` as a template method, and avoid all casting:

```
class UIManager {
public:
    template<typename T> 
    T* add(T *element) {
      // do something with element
      return element;
    }
}
```

Then your client code becomes

```
button1 = manager->add(new Button(0, "Enter", Point(10, 10)));
```

Comment: This is exactly it. Thanks! I've never used templates before.

Comment: I find this solution mildly distressing, but I'm not sure why.  There's a problem you'll encounter with types when you try to code this - you need somehow to indicate that T must be a UIElement subclass.

Comment: @AlexBrown the idea is that "do something with element" requires a `UIElement*`, so if you attempt to pass anything incompatible you get a compile time error. I actually use this pattern somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the buttons to the variables inside the argument to add:

```
// somewhere in the header file
UIManager *manager;
Button *button1, button2;

manager->add(button1 = new Button(0, "Enter", Point(10, 10)));
manager->add(button2 = new Button(0, "Exit", Point(10, 50)));
```

Also remove the returned argument from the add method.

Comment: The return value could be useful though.

Comment: Only if the method might modify it.  Cf the init method in objective-c

Comment: Not only. `UIElement* e = manager->add(something returning a UIElement pointer);`.

Comment: I see what you mean, but it seems un-necessary to me.

Comment: It might be difficult to keep a handle on these inerted pointers otherwise.

Comment: My point for returning the UIElement pointer was to reduce the amount of lines of code. So this is not the approach I'm looking for.

Comment: Okay, I've changed it to show a different method of reducing lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `add` method as a method template forwarding to the actual method:

```
class UIManager {
public:
    UIElement *add(UIElement *element);
    template<typename T> T *add(T *element) {
        return static_cast<T *>(add(static_cast<UIElement *>(element))); }
}

Button *button1 = manager->add(new Button(0, "Enter", Point(10, 10)));
```

Note that instead of raw pointers you should be using managed pointers (`unique_ptr` or, in this case, `shared_ptr`).

Comment: Why is it necessary to use smart pointers while I can assure that the elements will be destroyed in the Manager's destructor?

Comment: @drowneath exception safety; if `add` throws an exception then raw pointers will leak.